# Weird sifr character issue

Tags: flash, sifr

I've got the latest version of sifr working fine except that for one letter, it is looking very odd.

the font is 'Tiresias LPfont' and for a uppercase 'O' it is creating a weird line through it at the top:

http://tinypic.com/r/25qyflt/3

I've tried it every other letter uppercase, characters before and after it. In flash, when I create the swf file it looks fine in flash.

When I copy and paste it from the browser to Word, notepad, etc, it pastes as a normal 'O'.

Tried loads of other fonts and they all work fine.

So any idea what the heck is going on?

Ta

Answer (score 0):

Where'd you get the font?

http://new.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/tiresias/lpfont/

This guy? Legit or cracked? Have you tried typing the same text into another Flash movie with a dynamic text field and exporting that? Take sifr out of the equation and see if it's a broken font first.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying.

Font is legit and part of our studio font package. Tried it as a dynamic font in Flash and it looks fine and renders as a swf just fine.

Comment: Right on. Do you have a "live" version of the site? Maybe it's a browser issue? Any luck in any browsers?